# how do i point docker to the host syslog

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

On the host machine I have install syslog. Now when I want to run docker on the same host machine what value do I put for syslog-address? How do I find the port that is assigned to the syslog?

```
docker run \
      --log-driver syslog --log-opt syslog-address=udp://1.2.3.4:1111 \
      alpine echo hello world
```

Comment: The syslog Port usually is 514.

Answer (score 0):

The default UDP syslog port is 514.
Check syslog-ng.conf to configure a different port/network source.